# How to read PHP Variable in another file using ajax or jquery or javascript

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I am trying to solve it but it fails. I have send a form submission from one page `one.php` to another page `two.php` using ajax and its working fine.

Now I want to get/read the variable (which was created in `two.php` after I submitted the form) from the other page `two.php` in my first page `one.php` after submission function and use it in my ajax code for redirecting to another page `three.php` like `page.php?id=id` that exists in `two.php` but using it in `one.php`.

So in short,

1. I submitted a form from `one.php` to `two.php`.
2. A variable $output was created in `two.php` which I need in `one.php` inside a javascript/ajax function.

One.php,

[one.php](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mjc6v.png)

Two.php:-

[two.php](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9iX2Z.png)

**help is needed.**

Comment: please share code here instead of images

Comment: Doesn't using the METHOD acessor you used help? i.e. `$_GET[<input name>]`?

Comment: Have you had a look at the jQuery reference for [ajax()](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/)? The function you specifiy for `success` gets the data as its first parameter...

Comment: actually there is no such code, its just I want to read/get a php variable which exists in two.php file into one.php file inside a javascript/ajax/jquery function.

Comment: @kastenbutt yeah i am also confused. Just used it inside that function thinking that this function will run after successful form submission

Comment: @AlexanderSantos if I use GET thing, i will need to come back /refresh one.php which I didnt want hence used ajax so the page won't get refreshed and form gets submitted using two.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in the php file

```
echo $last_id;
```

and then

```
success: function (result) {
var last_id = result;
...

}
```